# Properties of Hadamard Manifold

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Since we know that  $\mathbb{H}^{2} \times \mathbb{H}^{2}$ is Hadamard manifold. It is written in the paper " Equidistance surface of the bidisc"  that $\textbf{Every sphere bounds a ball that is strictly convex}$. Can someone explains me whether it is property of Hadamard manifold or it is some theorem about Hadamard manifold.

Comment: Have a look at "Convex sets in Hadamard manifolds" by A.A Borisenko Differential Geometry and its Applications
Volume 17, Issues 2–3, September 2002, Pages 111–121 (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S092622450200102X)